# Hibernate dialect for Hive/SparkSQL?

Tags: hibernate, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have an app that used to connect to `MySQL`, and I have `Hibernate` config
for it like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://somehost:3306/some_db</property>
       ...
```

Now if I want to connect to `Hive/SparkSQL` instead, what would the 
equivalent values for these properties be?

I have some ideas on `driver_class` and `url` (assuming we are using port `10000`), but what should the `dialect` be?

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hive2://someHost:10000</property>
```

**Update**

I tried many different values but none of them work. (I have yet 
to find out what metastore the Apache Hive installation uses, so here
I was just doing trial-and-error)

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenFiveDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
```

I noticed that in all case, there is a warning from 
Hibernate that said:

```
WARN JdbcServicesImpl,main:160 - \
  HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : \
  Method not supported
```

And then the code would run into a `NullPointerException`
in `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure()` 
(Line 207 in 4.2.0.Final).

I downloaded the source code of Hibernate and traced the logic.
The exception was caused because a few line ahead a variable
`dialect` (of type `Dialect`) was determined to be `null` due to 
an exception caught when trying to execute Line 138:

```
metaReportsDDLCausesTxnCommit = meta.dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit();
```

The exception was

```
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
```

(that caused the above warning message)

Does that mean I cannot use `Hibernate` with Apache Hive?
If that is the case, then so be it.  (I guess I would have
to swap out the `Hibernate` implementation for this part)
But I am curious to know the authoritative answer
on this.

On the Internet I could not find strong evidence that 
people have been using `Hibernate` successfully with Apache Hive.

Comment: If you only care about the Hive metastore (like SparkSQL), you can use the Mysql, Oracle10, Derby, or Postgres dialect depending on what your metastore uses

Comment: @cricket_007 -- Thanks!  How can I know what the metastore uses? (Sorry if this sounds too ignorant --  This data lake is set up by someone else.) Is there a command that I can run? Or a file that I can look up?

Comment: Usually, I would try to find the hive-site.xml file, and some property containing  `jdo`. I'm not not suggesting that's what you need, simply that SparkSQL doesn't use JDBC to talk to HiveServer2

Comment: @cricket_007 -- Thanks for your help so far.  I added some updated information.  Can you give me some more comments or suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you can connect to the Hive Metastore using the correct dialect, but you need to scan your xml config to know what database that is... And your connection to **that database** would be no different than any other RDBMS with Hibernate. Again, you need to connect to the metastore database, not HiveServer2... I've not seen anyone use Hibernate or any other ORM library with Hive, but you may try Apache Gora. http://gora.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.

I think the answer is "No -- there is no dialect for Hive/SparkSQL" for Hibernate.  Apparently there are no support for HiveServer2 (i.e. not the Hive Metastore) in Hibernate.  I believe this is true (95% confidence) as of now (2017-10-19).

In my case, I ended up rewriting my code and replacing the Hibernate code to  direct JDBC code instead.  I was lucky that the Hibernate code there was just for simple DB query (`session.createSQLQuery()`) not serious ORM, so the change was relatively easy.