# Hive connection using hibernate in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hive

I am using spring boot to create hive apis.

Inside spring boot, I want pagination as well.

In application.properties my code is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

Error I am facing is :

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Hive do not have username and password.

Is this way of Hive connection is correct? Or I cannot connect hive using hibernate. If yes, Please suggest me other way and share some links if you have.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739044/hibernate-dialect-for-hive-sparksql

Comment: Thanks for reference. In this approach I may not be able to do pagination. I have millions of records in table.

Answer (score 0):

Officially hibernate is not compatible with Hive(as Jan 2018). Here is the [list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html).  But the closest dialect to Hive's syntax is mysql's dialect. You can set `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` and if you are lucky it may work in your case for pagination. You can try and share the result.